# Crawl not complete and error in Crawl log Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has

Tags: enterprise-search, crawl, 2019

In SharePoint 2019 farm  enabled min role ApplicationWithSearch Role and crawler component enabled in this server when I run full crawl for a content source below error occurred in crawl log and no items indexed.

I have below SharePoint Farm Topology :

2 Servers - ApplicationwithSearch Minrole

2 Servers - Search Minrole

1 Server - Front-end with Distributed Cache Minrole

3 Server - Front-end  Cache Minrole

Default content acess account has full permissions to content source and LoopbackCheck is disabled in all servers.

The start address http://xxxxx  cannot be crawled.

Context: Application 'Search_Service_Application', Catalog 'Portal_Content'

Details:
    Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read" permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled.   (0x80041205)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have not provided the crawl account with Full Read permissions in the User Policy for the target Web Application.

Comment: i have given full read permissions to Default Search Content access account, and i disabled loopback check in all WFE and search server role servers.